# DataTable Compute Variance negative results

Tags: c#, datatable, statistics

In my DataTable there is a column with type double. I want to calculate the statistical variance, but the result is negative. How can this be? Variance should always be positive, I guess. Can anyone tell me, what's wrong here?

Does anyone know the formula behind the algorithm of `System.Data.DataTable.Compute(Var(x), "")` method?

I have tested this with the following code and recieved different results. This time (only short sample) positive result, but different from the expected result (manually : 6025,155... vs. automatically : 6165,275...)

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dt.Columns.Add("x", typeof(System.Double));

// Sample Data
dt.Rows.Add(197.8);
dt.Rows.Add(90.1);
dt.Rows.Add(90.1);
dt.Rows.Add(152.3);
dt.Rows.Add(74.7);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(12);
dt.Rows.Add(12);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(12);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(25.5);
dt.Rows.Add(18.7);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(0);
dt.Rows.Add(43.9);
dt.Rows.Add(59.3);
dt.Rows.Add(119.9);
dt.Rows.Add(32.3);
dt.Rows.Add(59.3);
dt.Rows.Add(168.7);
dt.Rows.Add(204);
dt.Rows.Add(214.1);
dt.Rows.Add(174.1);
dt.Rows.Add(196.3);
dt.Rows.Add(170.5);
dt.Rows.Add(171);
dt.Rows.Add(242.6);


dt.Columns.Add("x2", typeof(System.Double));

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    row["x2"] = Math.Pow(double.Parse(row["x"].ToString()), 2);
}

double average = double.Parse(dt.Compute("AVG(x)", "").ToString());

double avg2 = double.Parse(dt.Compute("AVG(x2)", "").ToString());

double varianceManually = avg2 - Math.Pow(average, 2);

double varianceAutomatically = double.Parse(dt.Compute("Var(x)", "").ToString());

Console.WriteLine("Manually: " + varianceManually); // The same result as in MS Excel
Console.WriteLine("Automatically: " + varianceAutomatically);
Console.WriteLine("Difference: " + (varianceAutomatically - varianceManually));
Console.Read();
```

Some Information about my environment:

- MS Windows 7 64-Bit Service Pack 1
- AMD A10-7800 Radeon R7, 12 Compute
  Cores 4C+8G 3.50 GHz
- 16 GB RAM
- Visual Studio 2010
- .NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Can you provide a snippet of code that works on it's own that demonstrates the issue?  I can't quite tell what you are aiming for from the snippet you posted.

Comment: A commonly-implemented formula for the variance is mean(X^2) minus (mean(X))^2. That is mathematically correct, but it can yield a small negative number as a result of floating point round-off error when all the values of X are equal (i.e. X is a constant). If the value you are getting is on the order of the floating point epsilon (approximately 10^(-16)) then that's a possible explanation. If it is a relatively large number, maybe something else is happening. You'll have to post the values of productionData and tell what library is supplying the class of productionData and its Compute method.

Comment: Thank you Robert. I've already implemented this commonly formula manually (even in Excel) to validate the results. I'm using `System.Data.DataTable` and the Standard `Compute()` Method. I've got more than 100.000 records of Data and sometimes a lot of values are 0 consecutively. Maybe that's what causes the Problem. I will check this.